# Find length of an object using Handlebars Helpers

Tags: object, handlebars.js, helper

I am trying to write a helper which takes an object as a parameter and returns it's length. This length is to be assigned to rowspan of a td in a table. This is what i am trying to do

```
'getRowSpan': function(opts) {
     return Object.keys(opts.fn(this)).length;
 }
```

And in the table i do

```
<td rowspan="{{#getRowSpan logs}}">
```

where logs in an object that i have.

I don't know where i am going wrong.
Can anyone help me out in this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what `opts.fn(this)` is supposed to be doing. Based on your description, I think the helper you are looking for is:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getRowSpan', function (context) {
    return Object.keys(context).length;
});
```

Next, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903244/3397771), the '#' is for [block helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html). `getRowSpan` is not a block helper, so it should be accessed like:

```
<td rowspan="{{getRowSpan logs}}">
```

**EDIT:**
It is clear from the question that there is some confusion about the context and the options parameters that are passed to the helper. I am replacing the identifier, `opts`, from my handler with `context` to make it clear that we are calling `Object.keys()` on the context object and not the options hash.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton for helping out.